# Is it possible to catch MessageBox closing?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, messagebox

Is there any way for detect MessageBox closing. Some workarounds can be possible maybe I can write my own custom MessageBox, but I want the operating system's MessageBox.

Maybe something like `MessageBox.Closing += new EventHandler`, any suggestions?

Comment: Can you explain the purpose?

Comment: i have to set a flag to true when it's opening, and set the flag to false when closing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the MessageBox found int [Extended WPF Toolkit™ Community Edition](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MessageBox).

In its documentation there are two events called

```
CloseButtonClicked 
Closed
```

But as explained in the [Tigran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/156695/tigran) answer, the MessageBox.Show call is modal and block the thread in which you make the call, so there is no need to catch the close event unless you are running another thread that should react immediately in some way to the closing of the messagebox.

Answer (score 5):

There is no "normal" way of doing that, if not using some not very riliable API calls and sniffing. But according to yuor comment, you need may be something like:

```
var flag = true; 
MessageBox.Show(...); 
flag = false;
```

This is a correct way of doing that.  `MessageBox.Show(...);` is a blocking call.

If you need more control, define your *own* form, and it wil become *your* message box. 
So you can have full control over it, and have also `Closing` event handler possibility.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just wanted to see if the MessageBox was clicked and then do something, hope it helps.

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Your message");

    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Application.Exit(); //whatever you want
    }
```